# Highlight datatables row depending on incoming JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, datatable

I have a datatables table which uses ajax to source some json.  At present this is all working well but I would like to add something whereby all rows in the table with a particular attribute, say Highlight=True, have some additional css apllied to them.

I understand it is easy to do this for all rows or selected rows given in html format but I don't see how to do apply it to data on-the-fly so to speak.  A more general goal which I am working towards would be to apply some javascript or css to a row based on the data in that row.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: I would check out this "fnRowCallback (http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks)".  You can check to see if your data contains the data you want to apply the css to and add a class to that row if it does.

Comment: Can you give us a working example? jsfiddle, for example, supports JSON.